# Count children of a parent in recursive CTE

Tags: postgresql, cte, recursive

I use this query to find comments by a parent `id`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, content, path, parent_id, depth)  AS (
    SELECT  id,
        content,
        array[id] AS path,
        parent_id,
        1 AS depth
    FROM    comment
    WHERE   id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  comment.id,
        comment.content,
        cte.path || comment.id,
        comment.parent_id,
        cte.depth + 1 AS depth
    FROM    comment
    JOIN cte ON comment.parent_id = cte.id
    WHERE depth < 3
    )
    SELECT id, content, path, parent_id, depth FROM cte
ORDER BY path LIMIT 200;
```

It works well except I'm limiting the depth to 3. How can I find out if the current row has more children and if so get the count of them so I can display the number, ex. "Load X more".

What is the best way to go about this?

In [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1c423/1), `id` 4 and 5 have children, so I want to count them.

Answer (score 5):

To count *all* children, there is no way around following each path to the last element. You can then *show* rows down to some depth while counting the rest:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, parent_id, content, array[id] AS path
   FROM   comment
   WHERE  id = 1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.content, cte.path || c.id
   FROM   comment c
   JOIN   cte ON c.parent_id = cte.id
   )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (path[1:2])
       id, parent_id, content, path
     , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY path[1:2]) - 1 AS children
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY path[1:2], path <> path[1:2]
LIMIT  200;  -- arbitrary limit, unrelated to the question
```

[**SQL fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e84c5/1)

`path[1:2]` is the ***array slice*** from the 1st up to the 2nd element. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING)

This works for a depth of 2. Replace all occurrences of `1:2` with `1:3` to do the same for a depth of 3 etc.

The main feature is to "group" by the first n elements of the path. Apply the technique laid out in this related question:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194088/939860)

The last `ORDER BY` expression `path <> path[1:2]` produces a boolean result that is only true for the root element of the group (where the whole path is equal to the leading elements), and `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`. You could simply use `path` instead - not sure which performs better.